# USB partition not recognised in bios of intel D945GTP

Tags: bios, usb-boot

Using disk utility on macOS Big Sur, I have formatted a USB drive and it is now "USB External Physical Disk • GUID Partition Map." The partition is seen as "USB External Physical Volume • Windows NT File System (NTFS)"

I then used Etcher to flash the latest hiveos image onto it. I booted one computer from this flash drive into hiveosand it worked perfectly (ie nothing wrong with the usb drive).

On another computer, although the Physical disk (USB External Physical Disk • GUID Partition Map.) is recognised, the Physical volume (USB External Physical Volume • Windows NT File System (NTFS)) is not.

It needs to read boot from this partition but cannot see it.

I have no other hard drive attached.
I have enabled USB boot in the Bios
I have enabled "boot usb devices first" in the Bios
I have set the drive order (although there is only the USB attached so this is irrelevant)

Again, the bios CAN see the USB, but CANNOT see the partition with the bootable OS on it. When using a HDD with windows XP on it, the same computer boots fine

Using the same USB another machine, it boots as expected from the partition.

Comment: Etcher usually overwrites all partitions and partition tables anyway. Please check again the current drive layout. // Your old device would not support UEFI booting, of course.

Comment: I have checked and can confirm that the usb drive layout is as follows:  
JetFlash Transcend 32GB Media - USB External Physical Disk - GUID Partition Map.  
HIVE - USB External Physical Volume - Windows NT File System (NTFS).  
See images as per disk utility on my mac: https://imgur.com/a/wjxVJpE

Comment: Please add this information to your question. Use the image upload tool here. // I can guarantee you that NTFS is not the problem, because this is Linux we’re talking about. It wouldn’t be using NTFS for anything. // HiveOS is not free, so I cannot provide more specific advice.